# error 80070005 access denied

Tags: asp.net

I am getting the error 80070005 access denied while trying to create a ms-word document dynamically through the c# code. For this I have to register COM Library to IIS.

I want to know how to register a COM Library to IIS using regsvr32.

Please help.

Thanks and Regards,
Manu

Comment: You need to provide way more details before anyone can reasonably answer. Are you also aware that installing Office components on a server to be accessed from a website can be very expensive to licence correctly? (assuming that your `asp.net` tag is correct).

Comment: agree with slugster. it's also not recommended doing office automation on a server: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757. Try aspose products for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this link:
http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2006/03/02/589.aspx

You do not need to register Ms word, when you install the office, it will be in the DCOM list.
If you still cannot find it see this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828550